# How to make a toast when parsing data from json is null or no result?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a little problem with make a toast when my table database is null based on parsing json. I mean, when data is no result or no data found then make a toast " Sorry no data found". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**here my code for show the data**

```
private void showEmployee(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(konfigurasi.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_ID);
            String nama = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_NAMA);
            String pyg = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_PENYELENGGARA);
            String tmpt = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_TEMPAT);
            String tgl = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_TGL);
            String jam = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_JAM);
            String email = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_EMAIL);

            HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_ID,id);
            employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_NAMA,nama);
            employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_PENYELENGGARA,pyg);
            employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_TEMPAT,tmpt);
            employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_TGL,tgl);
            employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_JAM,jam);
            employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_EMAIL,email);
            list.add(employees);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this for postexcetude code :

```
private void getJSON(){
class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    ProgressDialog loading;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(TampilSemuaPgw.this,"Mengambil Data","Mohon Tunggu...",false,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(s == null || s.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (loading.isShowing())
            loading.dismiss();
        JSON_STRING = s;
        showEmployee();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
        String s = rh.sendGetRequest(konfigurasi.URL_GET_ALL);

        return s;
    }
}
GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
gj.execute();
```

}

**Update Code** by  KeLiuyue :

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    String s = rh.sendGetRequest(konfigurasi.URL_GET_ALL);
    return s;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        if(jsonArray.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (loading.isShowing()){
               loading.dismiss();
            }
            return;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("TAG",s);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (loading.isShowing())
        loading.dismiss();
    JSON_STRING = s;
    showEmployee();
}
```

Comment: have you checked  that showEmployee() returns something?

Comment: Are you sure the string being returned from doInBackground is null or empty?

Comment: im not sure @NabinBhandari, so, do you have any suggest for my doinbackground code? i just wanna make a toast or go to another activity when no data to display..please help, thankyou

Comment: Looks like some message is coming from the server even if there is no data. Try logging the data which is being received from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your code .

```
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    String s = rh.sendGetRequest(konfigurasi.URL_GET_ALL);
    return s;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    // edited here
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        if(jsonArray.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (loading.isShowing()){
               loading.dismiss();
            }
            return;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("TAG",s);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (loading.isShowing())
        loading.dismiss();
    JSON_STRING = s;
    showEmployee();
}
```

1.Determine return value whether is empty in `doInBackground` method

2.Determine param value whether is empty in `onPostExecute` method

Comment: You can try again. I remove something.@RizkiDeddySusanto

Comment: @NabinBhandari I removed it .

Comment: still nothing happen

Comment: Do you have data in `JSON_STRING` ?Did you `ListView` display in your device?

Comment: yes, i display json in a listview.. i mean when JSON_String is no data, then display or toast something like "No data"..

Comment: And I meant that you have data in the ListView ,then ,the Toast will be not diaplayed .

Comment: no, i mean that no data to display in listview (based json parsed), then display a toast "No data"

Comment: here the log "W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented"

Comment: sory, here the Log info after i add Log in "E/TAG: {"result":[]}"

Comment: So your response is not null .You must parse it .Then show the Toast.

Comment: thank you bro, toast "No data" finaly appear..but new problem is, the Progres dialog can not close

Comment: You can check again.

Comment: great, thank for your kindness, finaly my question answered.. thanks again @KeLiuyue

Comment: Could  you upvote and accept my answer?@RizkiDeddySusanto

Answer (score 0):

You need to Debug this issue why your toast is not showing:

You have correctly put show Toast code in onPostExecute

Now to debug , first put a Log to know the value of s , whether it is ever null or empty.

If yes and still toast is not showing, move the dialog dismiss dialog before Toast and check.

If Toast still does  not show debug your showEmployee() method as what it does.